# How to rotate image plane and take its projection visible on the screen?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation

I need a way to rotate a given image plane along an axis of which the ends are specified by the user. After the desired rotation the user must be able to get the projection of the image which he is looking at in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
rotate(h,direction,alpha)
```

rotates the graphics object h by alpha degrees. direction is a two- or three-element vector that describes the axis of rotation in conjunction with the origin of the axis of rotation. The default origin of the axis of rotation is the center of the plot box. This point is not necessarily the origin of the axes.

Positive alpha is defined as the righthand-rule angle about the direction vector as it extends from the origin of rotation.

More detail is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93690-how-do-i-rotate-or-flip-a-polar-plot)